# Conditional filters in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following dataset in which I need to find out the minimum date out of all records for each customer (f1) and list out the records whose date is greater than min date

```css
f1   f2  f3
101 JOE 2015-01-01
101 JOE 2015-31-01
101 JOE 2016-01-01
101 JOE 2016-04-01
101 JOE 2016-09-01
101 JOE 2016-31-01
101 JOE 2017-01-01
102 KAT 2015-21-01
102 KAT 2015-05-01
102 KAT 2016-02-01
102 KAT 2016-04-01
102 KAT 2016-09-01
102 KAT 2016-31-01
102 KAT 2017-02-01
```

```css
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (f1:int, f2:chararray, f3:date);
G = GROUP A BY (f1, f2);
DUMP G;

((101,JOE),{(101,JOE,2015-01-01),(101,JOE,2015-31-01),(101,JOE,2016-01-01),(101,JOE,2016-04-01),(101,JOE,2016-09-01),(101,JOE,2016-31-01),(101,JOE,2017-01-01)}
((102,KAT),{(102,KAT,2015-02-01),(102,KAT,2015-05-01),(102,KAT,2016-02-01),(102,KAT,2016-04-01),(102,KAT,2016-09-01),(102,KAT,2016-31-01),(102,KAT,2017-02-01)}


Output:

101,JOE,2015-31-01
101,JOE,2016-01-01
101,JOE,2016-04-01
101,JOE,2016-09-01
101,JOE,2016-31-01
101,JOE,2017-01-01
102,KAT,2015-21-01
102,KAT,2016-02-01
102,KAT,2016-04-01
102,KAT,2016-09-01
102,KAT,2016-31-01
102,KAT,2017-02-01
```

min date for first record is 2015-01-01,so i want the records > 2015-01-01
min date for second record is 2015-05-01,so i want the records > 2015-05-01

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Get the minimum date for each grouping,add it to all records and then use it to filter.

```
A = LOAD 'test30.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (f1:int, f2:chararray, f3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,ToDate(f3,'yyyy-MM-dd') as f3;
G = GROUP A BY (f1, f2);
M = FOREACH G GENERATE FLATTEN(A),MIN(A.f3) AS min_date;
F = FOREACH (FILTER M BY f3 > min_date) GENERATE f1,f2,f3;
DUMP F;
```

[image: Output]